# Могу ли я изменить скорость прокрутки с помощью React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, прокрутка

Мне надо изменить скорость прокрутки в полном открытии страницы, страница должна быть плавной когда прокручиваешь.

Надо чтобы `body` элемент была плавной, как на этом сайте: https://geona-dveri.ru/

Заранее спасибо !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть крутой [пакет](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@studio-freight/react-lenis) для такого скролла который легко внедряется и контроллируется

Уставнока:

```
npm i @studio-freight/react-lenis
```

Пример

```
import { ReactLenis, useLenis } from '@studio-freight/react-lenis'

function Layout() {
  const lenis = useLenis(({ scroll }) => {
    // called every scroll
  })

  return (
    <ReactLenis root>
      { /* content */ }
    </ReactLenis>
  )
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]